# Print to bluetooth printer on react-native

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-printing

Is it possible to print text to bluetooth printer using react native? There are libraries for bluetooth ble, but it's not clear how to do that.

Some [ble library](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx) and [this](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager) too

Thanks a lot for your response

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the function by using [react-native-bluetooth-serial](https://github.com/rusel1989/react-native-bluetooth-serial), the example is working with some changes. But in the documentation, it's not clear how to do print. Just use the write function in the example, write parameter is string. Add the '\n' after write parameter and it will work.

Comment: Can this be used to print to any bluetooth capable thermal printer (such as in link below) without having to delve into java-level programming with the accompanying SDK?  [link](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/GOOJPRT-PT-210-58MM-Bluetooth-Thermal-Printer-Portable-Wireless-Receipt-Machine-For-Windows-Android-iOS/32829535338.html)